# Can't get button component value onClick

Tags: reactjs

I'm sure this is something trivial but I can't seem to figure out how to access the value of my button when the user clicks the button. When the page loads my list of buttons renders correctly with the unique values. When I click one of the buttons the function fires, however, the value returns undefined. Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong here?

Path: `TestPage.jsx`

```
import MyList from '../../components/MyList';

export default class TestPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};

    this.handleButtonClick = this.handleButtonClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleButtonClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("button click", event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.lists.map((list) => (
          <div key={list._id}>
            <MyList
              listCollection={list}
              handleButtonClick={this.handleButtonClick}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Path: `MyListComponent`

```
const MyList = (props) => (
  <div>
    <Button onClick={props.handleButtonClick} value={props.listCollection._id}>{props.listCollection.title}</Button>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.target.value` is for getting values of HTML elements (like the content of an input box), not getting a React component's props. If would be easier if you just passed that value straight in:

```
handleButtonClick(value) {
    console.log(value);
}

<Button onClick={() => props.handleButtonClick(props.listCollection._id)}>
    {props.listCollection.title}
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not using the default button but instead some sort of customized component from another libray named Button.. if its a customezied component it wont work the same as the internatls might contain a button to render but when you are referencing the event you are doing it throug the Button component